# ASCII: weakness

Tags: encryption

Suppose I have an encryption function $e$ of a symmetric cipher with plaintext space

$$\mathcal{M}=\{1,2,\ldots,2^{24} \}.$$

Now, consider a list $L$ of integers:

$$67, 114, 121, 112, 116, 111.$$

Decoding $L$ with the ASCII encoding scheme (see http://www.asciitable.com/) gives the word (plaintext) **Crypto**.

My teacher says that there is a weakness in using the ASCII encoding scheme together with the above mentioned cipher, such that encoding and encrypting the word **Crypto** results in the six ciphertexts

$$e(67),e(114),e(121),e(112),e(116),e(111).$$

I do not understand the claim: Any hints?

Comment: Looks like this is basically ECB mode. Look up ECB mode weaknesses.

Comment: I notice you've just edited your question to clarify it. Was that for any future readers (if so, thanks!) or does my answer not solve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per request, some hints. Suppose you are an eavesdropper and you intercept the encryption of 'Crypto'.

- What is the encryption of `p`?
- What is the encryption of `CopytopCrypto`?
- If we were able to get the message `abc...zAB...Z .,"` encrypted, what messages could we calculate the encryptions of then?
- $(\dagger)$Suppose you intercepted a later message, which was either `Ya` or `No` (yes/no would be even easier to differentiate between since they are different lengths!). How could we use what we've learnt from intercepting `Crypto` to ascertain which message was sent?

As you will see, just intercepting the encryption of 'Crypto' has allowed us to create certain fake messages.

This [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) is known as [ECB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) has many weaknesses.

$(\dagger)$ Note that this assumes the encryption method was deterministic, which it may or may not be (in my area we always assume that $e(\cdot,\cdot)$ would be a deterministic function, where we 'supply' randomness as one of our inputs.

Comment: Thanks! As I understand it, this method of encryption is susceptible to decryption by frequency analysis (?).

Comment: That is also true, but is not one of the points I was making in my list - my point was that you already *know* what e('p') is if you knew that Crypto was encrypted...

Comment: Hmmm... So the encryption of p is e(112) and the encryption of CopytopCrypto is e applied to each letter. Hence, e applied to the second letter is e('o'); and so, if we know that a message of length two is sent, which is either the word Ya or No, then we can ascertain that it is No if the last sent ciphertext is e('o'); else, it is Ya. (?)

Comment: Correct. Note that the last point assumes that there is only one value of e('o') (but you've given the solution I had in mind).  If your question is answered, don't forget to mark it as such [and upvote if you found it helpful ;) ]. If not, you might want to consider updating the question to clarify what a good answer should do